# Magento 2.1.6 CE Direct post configure fields sent to authorize.net

Tags: magento-2.1, authorize.net

I've configured **Authorize.net Direct Post** as a payment method in Magento 2.1. This is a fairly restrictive account that requires a lot of fields and requests are failing because some data is not being sent to authorize.net.

In particular, it looks like `x_country` and `x_ship_to_country` are never sent. How can I configure the payments module to collect and send this information? I know it's captured in the checkout module.

This is the response from `https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll`:

> window.location="https://mywebsite.tld/authorizenet/directpost_payment/redirect/x_invoice_num/000000007/success/0/error_msg/Gateway
>   error: Bill To Country is
>   required./controller_action_name/directpost_payment/is_secure/1/";

And here's the debug log for one transaction, note that `x_country` and `x_ship_to_country` are blank:

```
[2017-05-30 18:57:54] main.DEBUG: array (
  'response' =>
  array (
    'x_response_code' => '3',
    'x_response_reason_code' => '33',
    'x_response_reason_text' => 'Bill To Country is required.',
    'x_avs_code' => 'P',
    'x_auth_code' => '',
    'x_trans_id' => '0',
    'x_method' => 'CC',
    'x_card_type' => 'MasterCard',
    'x_account_number' => 'XXXX0015',
    'x_first_name' => 'User',
    'x_last_name' => 'Lname',
    'x_company' => '',
    'x_address' => '1234 Sesame St',
    'x_city' => 'Houston',
    'x_state' => 'Texas',
    'x_zip' => '77013',
    'x_country' => '',
    'x_phone' => '1234567890',
    'x_fax' => '',
    'x_email' => 'dummy@data.com',
    'x_invoice_num' => '000000006',
    'x_description' => '',
    'x_type' => 'auth_capture',
    'x_cust_id' => '',
    'x_ship_to_first_name' => 'User',
    'x_ship_to_last_name' => 'Lname',
    'x_ship_to_company' => '',
    'x_ship_to_address' => '1234 Sesame St',
    'x_ship_to_city' => 'Houston',
    'x_ship_to_state' => 'Texas',
    'x_ship_to_zip' => '77013',
    'x_ship_to_country' => '',
    'x_amount' => '46.50',
    'x_tax' => '0.00',
    'x_duty' => '0.00',
    'x_freight' => '7.50',
    'x_tax_exempt' => 'FALSE',
    'x_po_num' => '',
    'x_MD5_Hash' => '706C267F8CA31058A740E0FC4BBCCB93',
    'x_SHA2_Hash' => '',
    'x_cvv2_resp_code' => '',
    'x_cavv_response' => '',
    'x_test_request' => 'false',
    'controller_action_name' => 'directpost_payment',
    'is_secure' => '1',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with this version of Magento 2. The fix is [on Github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/18da140df446c7c4795dd09d2952c0767303a634#diff-343460dc20572bca6aec307d1c41f717) but I've added it manually since a newer version of Magento is not available and there's no ETA for it.

Here's a summary of the changes:

In `app/code/Authorizenet/Model/Authorizenet.php` (or `vendor/magento/module-authorizenet/Model/Authorizenet.php` depending on your installation method) find these two lines:

```
->setXCountry($billing->getCountry())
...
->setXShipToCountry($shipping->getCountry());
```

And update them to

```
->setXCountry($billing->getCountryId())
...
->setXShipToCountry($shipping->getCountryId());
```

Then, for `app/code/Authorizenet/Model/Directpost/Request.php` find these two lines:

```
->setXCountry(strval($billing->getCountry()))
->setXShipToCountry(
            strval($shipping->getCountry())
         );
```

and update them to:

```
->setXCountry(strval($billing->getCountryId()))
->setXShipToCountry(
            strval($shipping->getCountryId())
         );
```

There may be a better way of doing this, but as Magento development isn't a primary focus for me this is good enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, the `x_description` field is not being set in the API DirectPost call to Authorize.net in Magento CE 2.2.2, so similarly to @charmeleon's solution, you can extend the `Directpost/Request` class, but it's probably more 'Magento-y' to write a plug in to attach the additional `setX[thing]` calls in an `afterSetDataFromOrder()` method, but either way works.